# Print only no-matching in list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I need help for something. I have a list like that :

```
bag = [['Empty'], ['Misc'], ['Empty'], ['Empty'], ['Empty'],]
```

And I want to print only the list different of `['Vide']`. But without using another list value. So I have try something like that :

```
for el != ['Empty'] in bag:
    print (el)
```

Or

```
for el in bag, with el != ['Empty']:
    print (el)
```

But nothing works. There is a lot of example in this website for matching or using known value... but I can't find solution for my situation.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *not using another list value*, but you can do it like this:

```
bag = [['Empty'], ['Misc'], ['Vide'], ['Empty'], ['Empty'], ['Empty']]

for ls in bag:
    if ls != ['Vide']:
        print(ls)
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Strange, I was think I have try this way doesn't work... Thank you.